# How to transfer the data from an iOS app to the same app running on an M1 mac?

Tags: macos, ios, apple-silicon

I have an iOs app which I have been using to track personal data. I have found the same app on the App store on my M1 mac and can run it successfully. But it is blank because it was installed from the app store.

Apple  has disabled sideloading of apps froman iOs device to an M1 mac (Apparently they cannot decide whether to allow it or not as they disabled and re-enabled this ability a couple of times. )

If I backup the iPhone and look in ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
I can see the backup(labeled cryptically with a number) and the 256 folders in it.
I can view the files in XCode but only see images.
Documents are blank.

Even using iMazing, I can see the app and even transfer it to the mac desktop as an '.imazingapp'. But i cannot open or even examine the app to get my data. XCode only shows an icon-I cant even look inside it. There is no option to show 'package contents' when ctrl-clicking on the file.

The app has no ability to export data, send emails, etc.

How can I transfer my data from this app to the app running on the M1 mac? Ideally I wish I could just 'sideload' the app from my phone and the data would come with it. But NOOO, Apple does not allow that. Or maybe I am just ignorant of a trick that you all know.

Comment: This is an issue with the developer of the app, you need to ask them. And you need to tell us what app you are referring to, maybe someone here has experience with it and can offer an answer.

Comment: please dont laugh too hard.........'my prostate pal'

Comment: Hey, half the planet has one ;-) But seriously you are more likely to get a useful answer out of the developer. Usually if it is possible to share data between Mac and iOS versions of the same app it is enabled via iCloud and either automatic or there is an account to sign into that allows syncing the data. Also there may be HIPAA regulations that make moving data around difficult, expensive or impossible.